# Google bot cannot fetch my web site - giving error 500 (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have tested my web site with all popular web browsers(chrome,ff,IE,Opera) all works fine.

After i added my web site to google web master tools,i see that google bot cannot fetch my site that giving error 500.

On details there is an error about **Application_AcquireRequestState** method which i implemented into globalasax that getting culture info.When a visitor change the language on web site all content is refreshing depending on selected language(culture).I donT understand how google bot cannot fetch the site when all browser's open site correctly.

Full error details:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.] globaltohum.MvcApplication.Application_AcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs e) +507 System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +148 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75 Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

This is the method in globalasax that set culture:

```
 protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          bool checkAdmin = false;
         //var lang="tr";
         var cultureInfo= new CultureInfo("tr");
        var handler = Context.Handler as MvcHandler;
        var routeData = handler != null ? handler.RequestContext.RouteData : null;
        if (routeData != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in routeData.Values)
            {
                if (item.Value.ToString() == "AdminEmrah")
                    checkAdmin = true;

            }
        }
         if (!checkAdmin)
         {
        var routeCulture = routeData != null ? routeData.Values["culture"].ToString() : null;
        var languageCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["lang"];
        var userLanguages = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages;
        var userLanguagesBrowser = Request.UserLanguages;
        CultureInfo ci;
        ci = new CultureInfo(userLanguagesBrowser[0].ToString());
        string stringCi = ci.Name;
        if (stringCi == string.Empty || stringCi == null)
            stringCi = "en";


        if (routeCulture == null && stringCi != null || stringCi != String.Empty && (stringCi.Contains("tr") || stringCi.Contains("en")))
            cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(stringCi);


        cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(
           routeCulture ?? (languageCookie != null
              ? languageCookie.Value
              : userLanguages != null
                  ? userLanguages[0]
                  : "en"));
           }

      if (cultureInfo == null)
            cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en");

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureInfo.Name);
    }
```

And this is the default route:

```
     routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { culture = "tr", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id   =    UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
```

Comment: The question is, are you sure that `userLanguagesBrowser[0]` this one is set? All the rest you check well, except here `ci = new CultureInfo(userLanguagesBrowser[0].ToString());`. As indicated by MSDN, it can be null: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userlanguages%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you , on debugging session userLanguagesBrowser[0] is set correctly when i try with newest browsers.I quess google spiders cannot understand these language requests.So i added another null check after userLanguagesBrowser now google can fetch the web site.